# How can I avoid running a Github Actions Job on a pull-request

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a GitHub action workflow that tests, builds and deploys. Quite common.

I want the job `test` to run on both main and PRs (into main). But I want the `build` and `deploy` to only run on pushes to main. How can I safely protect this?

The summarized `.github/workflows/ci.yml` looks like:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: "Lint, Test and Report"
        run: echo "running linter, then tests then report on this"
 
  build:
    needs: test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: "Build"
        run: echo "Building the artifacts"

  deploy:
    needs:
      - test
      - build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: "Deploy to Production"
        run: echo "Drumroll...."
```

I don't see any ENV variable or `github.x` attribute that indicates that this is a PR. Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Is it safe to match on branch-name instead? And e.g. use a

```
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/main')
```

to ensure we only ever run when the branch is `main`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is safe. However, change it to:

```yaml
if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
```

because otherwise somebody could push a branch `mainfoo` and you'd trigger the  job as well.

An alternative would be to check for the event name, like:

```yaml
if: github.event_name == 'push'
```

however I'd say this is less robust, since somebody could change the trigger above and remove the `branches: ..` part of the `push` trigger and suddenly you're deploying from PRs.